# Timezone conversion shows an offset of an hour more in OpenShift

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, openshift

I've implemented a REST webservice using flask. It stores and provides events information.

While storing information, I do the following steps:

- Take the date, time and timezone.
- Localize into the provided timezone
- Then convert it into utc timezone
- Finally get the utc timestamp and store it in the db.

  ```
  def __get_timestamp(_datetime):
      """Returns the timestamp from datetime
      """
      return time.mktime(_datetime.timetuple())

  def __strptime(formatted_dt, tzinfo):
      """Returns the utc timestamp after conversion from entered timezone to utc
      """
      tzinfo_dt = tzinfo.localize(datetime.datetime(formatted_dt['year'],     formatted_dt['month'], formatted_dt['day'], formatted_dt['hour'], formatted_dt['minute']), is_dst=True)
      utc = get_tzinfo()
      utc_tz = utc.normalize(tzinfo_dt.astimezone(utc))
      return __get_timestamp(utc_tz)

  def get_tzinfo(user_timezone="UTC"):
      """Return pytz timezone
      """
      return pytz.timezone(user_timezone)
  ```

While retrieving information

- Retrieve the utc timestamp
- Localize it into the utc
- Convert it into the required timezone
- Return with the required format

  ```
  def get_tzinfo(user_timezone="UTC"):
      """Return pytz timezone
      """
      return pytz.timezone(user_timezone)

  def __strftime(ts, tzinfo, format='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'):
      """Return the formatted datetime after converting utc timestamp to required timezone
      """
      utc = get_tzinfo()
      utc_dt = utc.localize(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts), is_dst=True)
      tzinfo_dt = tzinfo.normalize(utc_dt.astimezone(tzinfo)) 
      formatted_dt = tzinfo_dt.strftime(format)
      return formatted_dt
  ```

The sequence goes like this

Entered datetime = 2014-03-21 14:00

TimeZone = "Asia/Kathmandu" --> (GMT+05:45) Kathmandu

Resulting timestamp = 1395407700

Final Formatted Output = "2014-03-21 03:00 PM"

The problem seems to be with daylight saving because the same code gives the correct result when tested locally.

Currently the webservice is being run on [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) 
whose server has "EDT" timezone,
while my local settings has "NPT".

How can this be resolved?